# ¿Cómo puedo corregir el error "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'" en mi código?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio sobre cálculo de aguinaldo, se ejecuta bien, hasta que llega la hora de calcular el aguinaldo.

Este es el código

```
#Ejercicio final 

print("Por favor ingrese los datos del empleado")

#Variables de almacenamiento de datos del empleado
nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre completo: ")
dui = input("Ingrese su número de DUI: ")
nit = input("Ingrese su número de NIT: ")
salario_mensual = input("Ingrese su salario mensual en números: ")
salario_mensual = float(salario_mensual)
tiempo_empleado = input("¿Cuántos años lleva laborando en la empresa?: ")

#Calculo de aguinaldo
def sueldo_diario ():
    sueldo = int(tiempo_empleado)/30

def aguinaldo ():
    if (tiempo_empleado)>=1 and (tiempo_empleado)>=3:
        recibir = (sueldo * 15)
    elif (tiempo_empleado)>=4 and (tiempo_empleado)>=10:
        recibir = (sueldo * 19)
    else:
        recibir = (sueldo * 21)

#Generación de la boleta con los datos y aguinaldo a recibir del usuario
print("Boleta de pago/aguinaldo")

print("Nombre del ususario: ", nombre)
print("Número de DUI: ", dui)
print("Numero de NIT: ", nit)
print("Sueldo mensual: ", salario_mensual)
print("Tiempo laborado en la empresa: ", tiempo_empleado)
print("Aguinaldo a recibir: ", str(aguinaldo()))

print("Gracias, feliz navidad :)")
```

El error está en la línea 17 y línea 32.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MINEDUCYT\Desktop\Kattia archivos\Programación PythonBeca\ejercicios\ejerciciofinal.py", line 32, in <module>
    print("Aguinaldo a recibir: ", str(aguinaldo()))
  File "C:\Users\MINEDUCYT\Desktop\Kattia archivos\Programación PythonBeca\ejercicios\ejerciciofinal.py",  line 17, in aguinaldo
    if (tiempo_empleado)>=1 and (tiempo_empleado)>=3:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: `tiempo_empleado` es un string, ya que lo leíste con `input()`, el error es porque no se puede comparar un string con un entero. En qué te basarías para compararlos? Para solucionarlo, cuando lo lees hazle un cast a int-> `int(input("Ingrese su salario mensual en números: "))`. De esta manera, la variable siempre será un número y no tendrás problemas. Es muy buena práctica hacer los casteos cuanto antes, pues así te evitas tener que hacerlos cada vez que la usas, el error es porque ahí se te olvidó poner el casteo, tal como ***SI*** pusiste en la línea 14...

Answer (score 1):

Primero tienes que hacer un casteo de la variable tiempo_empleado ya que con el comando input recibe cadenas o tipo str por lo tanto no puedes comparar un str con un tipo int.

Segundo las funciones aguinaldo y sueldo diario no están retornando nada así que aunque soluciones el problema anterior cuando vayas a printear el aguinaldo sencillamente de va a devolver un "None". Acá te dejo una corrección del código, con las correcciones que debes tener en cuenta.

```
print("Por favor ingrese los datos del empleado")

#Variables de almacenamiento de datos del empleado
nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre completo: ")
dui = input("Ingrese su número de DUI: ")
nit = input("Ingrese su número de NIT: ")
salario_mensual = input("Ingrese su salario mensual en números: ")
salario_mensual = float(salario_mensual)
tiempo_empleado = input("¿Cuántos años lleva laborando en la empresa?: ")

#Calculo de aguinaldo

sueldo = int(tiempo_empleado)/30

def aguinaldo ():
    if int(tiempo_empleado) >=1 and int(tiempo_empleado) >=3:
        recibir = (sueldo * 15)
    elif int(tiempo_empleado)>=4 and int(tiempo_empleado)>=10:
        recibir = (sueldo * 19)
    else:
        recibir = (sueldo * 21)

    return recibir
#Generación de la boleta con los datos y aguinaldo a recibir del usuario
print("Boleta de pago/aguinaldo")

print("Nombre del ususario: ", nombre)
print("Número de DUI: ", dui)
print("Numero de NIT: ", nit)
print("Sueldo mensual: ", salario_mensual)
print("Tiempo laborado en la empresa: ", tiempo_empleado)
print("Aguinaldo a recibir: ", str(aguinaldo()))

print("Gracias, feliz navidad :)")
```